# Replacing a sequence $u_n \rightarrow u$, in $L^2$ by a sequence compactly supported.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-measure

Suppose we have a sequence of functions in $L^2(\Bbb R^n)$, $u_n$, that are (if necessary, compactly supported) and such that $u_n \xrightarrow{L^2} u$, where $u$ is comapctly supported in $K \subseteq \Bbb R^n$.

My question is:

> can we make a replacement $u'_n$  such that each $u'_n$ are supported in $K$ and $u'_n \rightarrow u$ in $L^2$ norm.

My thoughts are simply let $u'_n:= u_n1_K$. But I could not actually spell the argument out.

Comment: You are using $n$ in two ways.

Comment: You could let $u_m=u$ for all $m.$

Comment: That is right, ahah, but I was originally trying to modify functions $u_n$ which are continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. In general, if you know that $u_n\to u$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then it is true that $u_n|_K\to u|_K$ in $L^2(K)$ for any bounded, measurable subset $K$, just because
$$
\|u_n|_K-u|_K\|_{L^2(K)}\le \|u_n-u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}\to 0.
$$
and, of course, $\|u_n\mathbb{1}_K-u\mathbb{1}_K\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}=\|u_n|_K-u|_K\|_{L^2(K)}$